# Sublime Text Anaconda Error After Update

Tags: python, sublimetext3, anaconda

I use Sublime Text on Windows and Anaconda (the distribution software, not the Sublime Text plugin). After the latest update to Sublime Text (3.0 build 3143), I suddenly get this popup upon opening Sublime Text 3 with a Python file open:

> Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_process.LocalProcess object at Ox04CB7630> process can not start a new anaconda JsonServer in the operating system because: 
>   Anaconda can not spawn a new process with your current configured python interpreter (python) 
>   Make sure your interpreter is a valid binary and is in your PATH or use an absolute path to it, for example: C:\Python27\python.exe

I'm confused why this is happening because Python/Anaconda was working perfectly before I updated Sublime Text 3. I was able to run my files just fine. I didn't change any path or anything having to do with Python.

After closing this popup and attempting to run my Python file, I get this message:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\nsilverblatt\MSBA\BUS 672\HW1\672 HW1.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\nsilverblatt\MSBA\BUS 672\HW1]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda.exe;"C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS";C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Scripts\;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Scripts\R.exe;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;python;C:\Users\nsilverblatt\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.38.0-4\Library\share\graphviz]
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that switching the order of my environment variables fixed it; I moved the Anaconda3 path to the top under "Edit environment variables" and then after restarting Sublime Text 3, the Python files ran perfectly as usual.